# Using python's Threading module

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, kivy, python-multithreading

I am developing a python program that will eventually be able to perform different actions on a linux system (updates, internet speed test, display of machine information...) Some of these actions take time and my goal is to display a loading animation while the task is performed. This requires the execution of asynchronous functions and the use of the threading module.
I am only at the test phase of the program and I encounter a problem with the threading module, not only the function of the graphic interface of my program does not execute when I carry out the other actions but also at the end of the execution of the auxiliary functions the program crashes. Can anyone help me?

Thanks.

The code (python file):

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
import os
import threading



class MainWidget(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def maj(self):
        th2 = threading.Thread(target=os.system("echo 'user_password' |sudo -S dnf -y upgrade"))
        th2.start()







class TestApp(App):
    pass


th1 = threading.Thread(target=TestApp().run())
th1.start()
```

The code (.kv file):

```
MainWidget:

<MainWidget>:
    Button:
        text: "MAJ"
        on_press: root.maj()
    AsyncImage:
        source: "images/test.gif"
        pos: 300, 300
```

Translated with [www.DeepL.com/Translator](http://www.DeepL.com/Translator) (free version)

Comment: Do you have a traceback of the crash?

Comment: th1 starts in another thread so the main thread keeps executing and if it reaches end of the script it will exit even if th1 isn't finished

Comment: Don't try to run your App in another thread. Just replace the `th1` thread creation and start with `TestApp().run()`.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I removed the th1 and now the application doesn't crash, however the application freezes during the execution of the maj method, which makes the use of threading inefficient as you get the same result as if you hadn't used it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you are trying to accomplish, but the `os.system()` call executes the provided command in a new shell (See [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/os.html#os.system)). So, when you execute:

```
th2 = threading.Thread(target=os.system("echo 'user_password' |sudo -S dnf -y upgrade"))
```

The `os.system()` call is executed immediately (not in a new thread), and the `Thread` creation tries to schedule the return from the `os.system()` as its target. Then the `th2.start()` calls whatever the `os.system()` had returned (probably an exit code), and should produce an error.

Anyway, perhaps you should be using `subprocess.Popen()` instead of `Thread`. See the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor). This will run the provided system command in a new process and does not wait for its completion.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, I managed to solve my problem using subprocess.Popen(). Now my command runs in parallel with the rest of the program.